# Composer only loads when a character is added

Tags: php, composer-php

After initializing the Composer autoloader, I want to check the existence of a class:

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
var_dump(class_exists('PagesController'));
```

This gives me `boolean false`, as if my class doesn't exist. However, it does, and is mentioned in the classmap autoloading.

When I add a simple change in the `vendor/autoload.php`, like adding a `var_dump("ballon")`, the original check for the PagesController changes to `boolean true`.

[image: Screenshots from my IDE]

My composer.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "require": {
    "propel/propel": "~2.0@dev"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": ["controllers/", "views/", "views/helpers/", "controllers/components/", "models/", "generated-reversed-database/generated-classes/"]
  }
}
```

I've ran `php composer.phar install` to generate the autoloader.

`require_once('vendor/autoload.php')` includes the composer-generated file and is the very first line of code to be executed (it's in my `index.php`). The `PagesController` class is located in `controllers/`.

I'm running php 5.5.9 with Apache2 on an Ubuntu server.

It doesn't even matter whether its a `var_dump`, a comment (`//`), or simply a whitespace () that I add in `vendor/autoload.php`, as long as I add something.

My `autoload_classmap.php` file:

```
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    (...lots of classes...),
    'PagesController' => $baseDir . '/controllers/PagesController.php'
);
```

So the class is found and listed.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Can you add some more details?

Comment: I'll update the question with some more details, sec.

Comment: The one thing that sticks out for me is that you don't seem to be using a namespace for your PagesController class. I don't know why the var dump is affecting things (I suspect the explanation is more complex than that, but I can't see it), but the namespace may be having an effect. Have you tried putting var dumps into the actual autoload class so you can see what files PHP is actually trying to load to find the class?

Comment: could you please include also the content of your `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php` file?

Comment: @Simba There's a `var_dump` added in the picture attached in `autoload.php`, unsure what you mean? I also just found out that it doesn't matter what I add, as long as I add a character: even a whitespace has the same effect. 

@marcosh It's a really large file due to all the classes in my `generated-reversed-database` directory, so I've shortened it:
`$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    (...lots of classes...),
    'PagesController' => $baseDir . '/controllers/PagesController.php'
);`

Comment: I meant try var dumping in `autoload_real`; ie the actual autoload class that does the loading. That will show you what actual files the autoload is trying to read.

Comment: I think this problem must be dissected by removing parts that aren't needed, to isolate the source of the bug: Does it work in a new directory with only your one class, and only one directory in the classmap, and no external dependencies? If it works, add more stuff that your original has, until it breaks. What was added when it breaks?